# ¿Cómo usar f string en jinja en un template de django?

Tags: python-3.x, django

en la etiqueta < a> en el href, en la parte de la url quiero que se me valla generando el contenido que va iterando del for

```
     {% for state in states %}
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="{% url '{{state}}' %}">{{state}}</a>
      </li>
     {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Supongo que estás teniendo una confusión al intentar usar fstrings por errores extraños. Eso por que Python no sabe que llaves son placeholders y que llaves se deben escapar. La solución: escapa las llaves usando otras llaves:  `{{% for state in states %}}` y las que no hay que escapar, `{state}`. Otras opciones es usar el viejo formateo de cadenas (%s, mi favorita para estos casos), usar [string.Template](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/string.html#string.Template) o crear tu propio parser aprovechando [string.Formatter](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/string.html#string.Formatter)

Comment: Hola dante , gracias por contestar.  
No puedo asignar el contenido de la variable en la dentro del href="{% url '{{state}}' %}">después lo otro anda bien. Por eso preguntaba si se podía hacer algo parecido como en python 
var = "x"
print(f"{var}") o como el viejo formateo de cadenas como me comentabas

Comment: De nada! No entendí bien, pero el problema es que no estás escapando bien las llaves. Debería quedarte {{% url  {state)...

Comment: Oh, creo que logré entender. Lo que buscas es usar algo similar a los fstring en jinga. Voy a intentar ayudarte como pueda, pero la verdad no se nada de jinga

Comment: He leido la [documentación](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/templates/language/) y, no se dice nada sobre el formateo de cadenas. Pero, se me ocurre una posible solución: Algo que si se puede hacer es colocar variables con la sintaxis {{variable}}. Si django permite en su template concatenar cadenas, podrías usar la concatenación, algo como: `"{% url '" + {{state}} + "' %}"`. Se que no es la sintaxis más bonita, pero hasta podría ser la solución correcta.

Comment: Es posible! Mira [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4386168/how-to-concatenate-strings-in-django-templates) del sitio en inglés.